# Transforming one exponential expression to multiplication of exponential expressions

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following expression:

```
Exp[a * x + b * y + c * z]
```

I want to write this expression as:

```
Exp[a * x] * Exp[b * y] * Exp[c * z]
```

How can I force Mathematica to apply this change to an exponential expression?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mostly find my answer there. But may be there should be a better method for doing this manipulation. @Nasser

Answer (score 1):

The desired form automatically simplifies to your original expression, i.e.,

```
expr = Exp[a*x]*Exp[b*y]*Exp[c*z]

(* E^(a x + b y + c z) *)
```

Consequently, the desired form will need to be either held or inactive.

```
expr2 = expr /. E^t_ :> Times @@
    (HoldForm[Exp[#]] & /@ t)
```

[image]

```
expr2 // ReleaseHold

(* E^(a x + b y + c z) *)

expr3 = expr /. E^t_ :> Times @@
    (HoldForm[E^#] & /@ t)
```

[image]

```
expr3 // ReleaseHold

(* E^(a x + b y + c z) *)

expr4 = expr /. E^t_ :> Times @@
    (Inactive[Exp][#] & /@ t)
```

[image]

```
expr4 // Activate

(* E^(a x + b y + c z) *)

expr5 = expr /. E^t_ :> Times @@
    (Inactive[Power][E, #] & /@ t)
```

[image]

```
expr5 // Activate

(* E^(a x + b y + c z) *)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not an answer to my question because the initial expression is the unseparated form Exp[a * x + b * y + c * z] and not Exp[a * x] * Exp[b * y] * Exp[c * z].@Bob-Hanlon

Comment: As shown in the first two lines, `expr = Exp[a*x]*Exp[b*y]*Exp[c*z]` evaluates to `E^(a x + b y + c z)`; that is its stored value. That is exactly why the desired output must be held or inactive to keep the desired form. Each subsequent expression starts with `expr` which is `E^(a x + b y + c z)`